# Issue with google recpatcha using PHP

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I am using [google recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) in my website enquiry form. I have used cURL rather than `file_get_contents()`, because my server's **allow_url_fopen** is disabled due to security issues. Here is my code to validate the recaptcha:

```
        <?php
        $response=htmlspecialchars($_POST["captcha"]);
        $secret = "my_secret_key";
        $curl = curl_init();

        $captcha_verify_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$captcha_verify_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=".$secret."&response=".$response);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $captcha_output = curl_exec ($curl);
        curl_close ($curl);
        $decoded_captcha = json_decode($captcha_output);
        $captcha_status = $decoded_captcha['success']; // store validation result to a variable.
        if($captcha_status === FALSE){
          echo "fail";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "success";
        }
        ?>
```

My issue is when I check recaptcha, if I change the google url to anything or my secret key to anything, I get the response success. It shouldn't return success if secret key is not correct right? Even if I change the [google_verify_url](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify) I get the success response. I couldn't understand what is happening. Is there anything wrong from my side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a request with wrong parameters the response from curl will be `NULL` and not `FALSE`, thats why it always returns `success`. Also you have an warning, because you use an object as an array. This should be working:

```
$response = htmlspecialchars($_POST["captcha"]);
$secret = "my_secret_key";
$curl = curl_init();

$captcha_verify_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $captcha_verify_url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=".$secret."&response=".$response);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $captcha_output = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close ($curl);

 $decoded_captcha = json_decode($captcha_output, TRUE); // Changed the second parameter 
 $captcha_status = $decoded_captcha['success'];

 if($captcha_status == NULL){ // Changed False to Null
   echo "fail";
 } else {
   echo "success";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> assoc When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative
>   arrays.

```
$decoded_captcha = json_decode($captcha_output, true);
```

Better to catch the exception:

```
try {
 ......
} catch (Throwable $exception) {
   echo $exception;
}
```